# bash: String Operator with regular expression

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, terminal

I want to list all files in my `home` folder, and remove the `#` in the filename. 
For example:
`#.emacs#` should be printed out as `.emacs`

This is my code

```
for dir in $(ls ~)
do
    # trim trailing
    filename="${dir#\#}"
    echo ${filename}
done
```

But it's still showing files preceding with `#` though I managed the regular expression `${dir#\#}` in terminal.

Can you tell me where's the smell in my code?

Comment: It's not clear what is it that you're trying to achieve.  Could you give an example?

Comment: Can you show the file names "before and after"? Could it be that you need to escape your backslash (`filename="${dir#\\#}"`)?

Comment: It seems that you wanted to `mv` the files.  Instead of `echo`, say `mv "${dir}" "${filename}"`.

Comment: Ok, after your update you should see the first example in `BMW's` answer. You should also change your script to not parse `ls` though, unless you want to introduce other errors. (note you can remove the proceeding path characters with i.e. `"${dir##*/}"` or `basename "$dir"`)

Comment: @BroSlow: I'm mentioning this just in case the confusion is not accidental: I think you mean *pre*ceding, not *pro*ceeding - the latter means something else.

Comment: @mklement0 You're right. Not really relevant after edit anyway so removing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove `#` from filename, should be :

```
filename="${dir//#/}"
```

#### edit: in some systems (such as Solaris), above command doesn't work, you need escape.

```
filename="${dir//\#/}"
```

#### The rest are fine for both cygwin and Solaris.

If you need remove all contents before #

```
filename="${dir##*#}"
```

If you need remove all contents after #

```
filename="${dir%%#*}"
```

#### Here are full explanation I copy and paste from bash `Substring Replacement`

```
${string/substring/replacement}
Replace first match of $substring with $replacement.

${string//substring/replacement}
Replace all matches of $substring with $replacement.

${string%substring}
Deletes shortest match of $substring from back of $string.

${string%%substring}
Deletes longest match of $substring from back of $string.

${string#substring}
Deletes shortest match of $substring from front of $string.

${string##substring}
Deletes longest match of $substring from front of $string.
```

Comment: I tested in CYGWIN, what's your environment?

Comment: Add more explanations

Answer (score 1):

[Don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). You can just you [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) wildcard expansion instead. Also, your use of parameter expansion is wrong, `${word#something}` removes `something` from the prefix not the suffix. So try

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for dir in ~/*
do
  # trim trailing
  filename="${dir%#}"
  echo "${filename}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you just `echo` the filename but not to rename it. So first you need to `cd` to `home` directory from scripts then rename files. Please below scripts to find file name which contain `#` char and removed `#` from file name.

```
#! /bin/bash
cd ~
for i in $(ls ~ )
do 
 if [[ "${i}" == *#* ]]
 then
    var=$(echo "$i" | sed 's/#//' )
    printf "%s\n" "$var" #to print only
    #mv  "$i" "$var" #to renmae
 fi
done
```

Comment: I just want to print its name after stripping off #

Comment: @TruongHa ok, so you want just print it's name but not renamed it right then please see my edited post.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a - hopefully - instructive version:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Make pathname expansion match files that start with '.', too.
shopt -s dotglob

# Loop over all files/dirs. in the home folder.
for f in ~/*; do
  # Exit, if no files/dirs match at all (this test may 
  # not be necessary if `shopt -s nullglob` is in effect).
  # Use -f to only match files, -d to only match dirs.
  [[ -e $f ]] || break
  # Remove the path component ... 
  filename=$(basename "$f")
  # ... and then all '#' chars. from the name.
  filename="${filename//#/}"
  # Process result
  echo "${filename}"
done
```

- As others have noted, you should not parse `ls` output - direct pathname expansion of globs (wildcard patterns) is always the better choice.
- `shopt -s dotglob` ensures that files or dirs whose name starts with `.` are included in pathname expansion.
- Pathname expansions occurs with the path component intact, so to get the mere filename from the loop variable, `basename` must be applied (first), in order to strip the path component.
- Probably not an issue here, but unless `shopt -s nullglob` is in effect (not by default), a glob that matches nothing is left untouched, so the loop is entered with an invalid filename - hence the `[[ -e ... ]]` test.

Answer (score 0):

You didn’t state that your files have `#` at the start **and** end of filename earlier. Try something like:

```sh
for dir in ~/*; do 
    filename="${dir#\#}"
    filename="${filename%\#}"
    echo "$dir ---> ${filename}"
done
```

or use what [BMW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/498256/bmw) has shown as his first example:

```sh
for dir in ~/*; do 
    filename="${dir//#/}"
    echo "$dir ---> ${filename}"
done
```

Once you are satisfied with `echo`’s output. You can replace that with `mv`.

**P.S: Re-iterating what [BroSlow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3076724/broslow) stated. [Don’t parse ls.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)**